# what is this mobile app control called?

Tags: ios, navigation, categories, collectionview, segmentedcontrol

I'm starting to see more iOS app (Etsy, Lootsy, etc.) using this control to navigate through categories.  I"m thinking about implementing it in iOS where I can switch between collection views.   Anyone know what this is called and if there is a github repo to look at as starting point?

Thanks
[image: swipe between category control]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012279/ios-library-or-diy-etsy-like-category-control

Answer (score 0):

This implements similar Scrollview (doesn't have to be infinite)

```
 https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker
```